# Connecting to the MSSQL Docker container using a different port than 1433?

Tags: sql-server, docker, docker-compose

I'm able to run the MSSQL container easily enough using the instructions [from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-docker?view=sql-server-ver15&pivots=cs1-bash)

The issue is that because of the a locally running instance of MSSQL, I can't use port 1433.

I've changed the startup line to use `30303:1433`, but I'm unable to connect to the instance at `localhost:30303`.

Connecting to the container, I'm able to connect to the instance using the tutorial's command:

```
/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P "<YourNewStrong@Passw0rd>"
```

Answer (score 6):

Ok found the solution myself. It is just due to a SQL quirk.

Changing the address to `127.0.0.1,30303` works.

- Use a comma
- Don't use `localhost`; use `127.0.0.1` instead.